# How to pass a parameter to React from view

Tags: reactjs, .net-core

I'm pretty new to .NET Core and React.  I'm using .NET Core 3.1 with ReactJS.NET.  I have a controller that receives a song ID and my view is intended to display details about a song.

Detail.cshtml:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Song</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="@Url.Content("~/js/SongDetail.jsx")"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my React SongDetail.jsx content:

```
class SongDetail extends React.Component {
    // Constructor and methods to manage passing the data go here
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="song">
                Title:  {this.state.data.title}<br />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <SongDetail
        url="api/SongApi/17"
    />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

I'd like to have the ID of the URL be dynamic, passed along from the controller.  Then it could receive the data from an API call based on that ID in the component.

About the only technique I've found referenced is to store the ID to an INI or ENV file and read it in the jsx code.  This feels very clumsy to me but maybe it's more standard than I think.

I'm also beginning to wonder if it's better to skip React in this case and pass an object to the view to be used by @Model and just fill in the blanks in the HTML.

Is there a better way to pass an ID in react or is just passing data to be used by the view itself a decent option?

Comment: Have you tried building a function to process the path in the URL manually, or [react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) or some other react routing solution?

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks.  I have not.  The router seems an interesting idea.  I'm not clear where in the chain I'd add a URL processing function.  Would the React code have access to the URL?

Comment: If it's javascript running in a browser, then yeah. `window.location.href` [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)